# How to insert string to each token of a list of strings?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list-comprehension

Lets assume I have the following list:

```
l = ['the quick fox', 'the', 'the quick']
```

I would like to transform each element of the list into a url as follows:

```
['<a href="http://url.com/the">the</a>', '<a href="http://url.com/quick">quick</a>','<a href="http://url.com/fox">fox</a>', '<a href="http://url.com/the">the</a>','<a href="http://url.com/the">the</a>', '<a href="http://url.com/quick">quick</a>']
```

So far, I tried the following:

```
list_words = ['<a href="http://url.com/{}">{}</a>'.format(a, a) for a in x[0].split(' ')]
```

The problem is that the above list-comprehension just does the work for the first element of the list:

```
['<a href="http://url.com/the">the</a>',
 '<a href="http://url.com/quick">quick</a>',
 '<a href="http://url.com/fox">fox</a>']
```

I also tried with a `map` but, it didn't work:

```
[map('<a href="http://url.com/{}">{}</a>'.format(a,a),x) for a in x[0].split(', ')]
```

Any idea of how to create such links from the tokens of a list of sentences?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were close, you limited your comprehension to the contents of `x[0].split`, i.e you were missing one `for` loop through the elements of `l`:

```
list_words = ['<a href="http://url.com/{}">{}</a>'.format(a,a) for x in l for a in x.split()]
```

this works because `"string".split()` yields a one element list.

This can look *way prettier* if you define the format string outside the comprehension and use a positional index `{0}` informing `format` of the argument (so you don't need to do `format(a, a)`):

```
fs = '<a href="http://url.com/{0}">{0}</a>'
list_words = [fs.format(a) for x in l for a in x.split()]
```

With `map` you can get an ugly little duckling too if you like:

```
list(map(fs.format, sum(map(str.split, l),[])))
```

Here we `sum(it, [])` to flatten the list of lists `map` with `split` produces and then map `fs.format` to the corresponding flattened list. Results are the same:

```
['<a href="http://url.com/the">the</a>',
 '<a href="http://url.com/quick">quick</a>',
 '<a href="http://url.com/fox">fox</a>',
 '<a href="http://url.com/the">the</a>',
 '<a href="http://url.com/the">the</a>',
 '<a href="http://url.com/quick">quick</a>']
```

Go with the comprehension, *obviously*.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 2):

```
list_words = ['<a href="http://url.com/{}">{}</a>'.format(a,a) for item in l for a in item.split(' ')]
```

Comment: it's generally way better if you actually add a bit of an explanation to an answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

In **one-liner**:

```
list_words = ['<a href="http://url.com/{}">{}</a>'.format(a,a) for a in [i for sub in [i.split() for i in l] for i in sub]]
```

**In steps**

You can split the list:

```
l = [i.split() for i in l]
```

and then flatten it:

```
l = [i for sub in l for i in sub]
```

result:

```
>>> l
['the', 'quick', 'fox', 'the', 'the', 'quick']
```

Then:

```
list_words = ['<a href="http://url.com/{}">{}</a>'.format(a,a) for a in l]
```

You will finally take:

```
>>> list_words
['<a href="http://url.com/the">the</a>', '<a href="http://url.com/quick">quick</a>', '<a href="http://url.com/fox">fox</a>', '<a href="http://url.com/the">the</a>', '<a href="http://url.com/the">the</a>', '<a href="http://url.com/quick">quick</a>']
```